# Coordinate free computation of the second derivative of a functional

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-operators, vector-spaces

Let $F(g(f))$
be a functional that sends functions of a vector variable (from $n$-dimensional vector space) to $\mathbb R$.

$g$
is some function of scalar valued functions $f$.

I'm interested in a coordinate free calculation of the first and second derivatives of functionals on the spaces of real valued functions of a vector variable, where the vector space dimension can be more than 3.

It can be [shown](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Formula) using vector calculus that the first (order) functional derivative $\partial F$
is equal to the partial derivative of $g$
with respect to $f$
minus the divergence of the gradient of $g$.

\begin{gather*}
F=\int {f(x)} ^{4} dx^{4} \\
\partial F= \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{f}} - \nabla \cdot\nabla g(f).
\end{gather*}

Divergence of the gradient should be equal to $4$, and if I plug in the above functional into the formula on Wikipedia it should work just as well for 4d and I get the result: $ \partial F=−12f^{3}$.

Can I just plug this into the formula again and get the second derivative of the functional?

Comment: I didn't see your exact formula on the Wikipedia article, but it seemed quite close to the formula linked at "[Functional derivative > Formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Formula)", so I changed the link to point there (while also fixing up some TeX).  I hope that was correct.

Comment: Yea that's the one

Comment: The $\nabla \cdot \nabla $ term doesn't correspond to what's on the Wikipedia page and just seems simply wrong to me. The correct form on the Wikipedia page refers to the case that $g$, in your notation, contains $\nabla f$ (which it doesn't in your concrete example), and then one has to take into account $\partial g/\partial (\nabla f)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For
$$
F=\int d^4 z \ f^4 (z) \ ,
$$
the first functional derivative is
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta f(x)} = \int d^4 z \ 4 f^3 (z)\ \delta^4 (x-z)
=4 f^3 (x)
$$
and the second functional derivatives are
$$
\frac{\delta^{2} F}{\delta f(x) \delta f(y)} = 12 f^2 (x) \ \delta^4 (x-y)
$$

Comment: Are you sure, I don't know how to check this , I don't think it's quite right , and why does first contain the delta and the other one not .

Comment: Though I knew the Dirac function should be used at some point so that is a good sign

Comment: The double nabla is just the divergence of the vector gradient , which you have to take into account in my opinion because you have to compute how the function f changes spatially

Comment: So you're saying if the integrand doesn't depend on derivatives explicitly I can just find the first derivative by partial derivative and then make a functional out of the function I get with the Dirac function and then just take the derivative of that

Comment: @LeoKovacic - of course I'm sure. The reason there isn't a Dirac $\delta $ in the first derivative is because the integral has taken care of it, as explicitly written. When taking another derivative, there's no integral anymore. Your functional doesn't care about how $f$ varies, so that variation doesn't have to be taken into account. We're really really stretching what type of question should be posted on this site. These are not things you should expect to be explained to you here.